# Some questions about scripts in Gradle

Tags: jar, gradle, ear, pack, unpack

I have to write the script in Gradle and I therefore have some questions.

The script must unpack the .ear file, and then included in the jar, then edit the content and save as ear (text file> jar> ear.)

1) Firstly, I would like to learn how to save a file to the current directory.
(The following code saves the file to another folder.)

```
task unzip(type: Copy)  {
        def zipFile = file('C:/Test/file.ear')
        def outputDir = file('jar')
        from zipTree(zipFile)
        into  getDestDir() 
    }
```

Phrases such as '.', '/' don't work.

2)Secondly, I would like to ask how to unpack the jar file because I can't unpack the above method. (It works only to the EAR)

3)At the end I would ask how you can convert the edited text file on the jar, and then on ear (without dependencies and manifest).
Because the resulting file do I have to file .ear

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be writing files into your working directory. All the work should be done under the `$buildDir`.

A standard method is to set your `into` directory to a temporary location:

```
task myTask(type: Copy) {
   from 'my/dir/'
   into temporaryDir
}
```

You can unpack a JAR or ZIP file like so:

```
copy {
   from zipTree('path/tozip.zip')
   into temporaryDir
}
```